# Lot of strange leaks in instruments only on device (no leaks in simulator)

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, instruments

I started working with instruments and have a lot of leaks. I don't have an idea how to solve them.

Instrument show that i have leak in this line:

```
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchResultsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil]];
```

What is wrong with this?

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SearchResultsTableViewCell";

 SearchResultsTableViewCell *cell = (SearchResultsTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 if (cell == nil) {
  NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
         loadNibNamed:@"SearchResultsTableViewCell"
         owner:self options:nil]];

  for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
   if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
    cell = (SearchResultsTableViewCell *) currentObject;
    break;
   }
  }
  [topLevelObjects release], topLevelObjects = nil     ;
 }

    Product *product = [productMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 cell.textLabel.text = product.title;
 cell.detailTextLabel.text = product.desc1;
 UIImageView *imageView = nil;
 if (product.photo == nil) {
  imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ph38x38.jpg"]];
 } else {
  imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:product.photo];
 }
 imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10., 3., 38., 38.);
 [cell addSubview:imageView];
 [imageView release];

    return cell;
}
```

I also have a lot of other leaks, but instruments doesn't even show line in the code, for example there is a leak:
GenerlaBlock-64 - UIKit - GetContextStack
How can I solve it? where should i look for it?

I looked for some kind of tutorials, but all of them show only trival examples with retain count, alloc, release

Comment: Why do you need to `initWithArray:` with something that is already an autoreleased `NSArray`?

Comment: i fixed it but didn't solve the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Threads were making all the problems. I was doing forks all the time without returning to main thread. That was the problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, please?

Comment: Well, it was quite a long ago and I dont remember exactly. It was something connected with threads and UI i think (cant modify UI in threads). There were also a problem with multiple threads. I was launching new thred in that thread launhing new one and so on, without returning to main thread. It was simple and stupid bug.

Answer (score 4):

Threads aren't the real problem. It's the "text" property of UILabel.

```
cell.textLabel.text = product.title;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = product.desc1;
```

**This property can only be set on the main thread.**

Call performSelectorOnMainThread instead:

```
[cell.textLabel performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:product.title waitUntilDone:NO];
[cell.detailTextLabel performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:product.desc1 waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: I was having a similar problem and tried the above solution in desperation. It didn't fix my problem. I didn't expect it would because I'm pretty sure that iOS already calls tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath from the main thread. After all, it's part of the UIKit and UIKit calls can only be made on main thread. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just remove the `initWithArray:` and use

```
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
         loadNibNamed:@"SearchResultsTableViewCell"
         owner:self options:nil];
```

(and you have to remove the `release` and set `nil` line too)

// EDIT: try to set the `owner:nil`

Comment: didn't solve the problems. instruments still show same leaks :(

Comment: why do you create an UIImageView if you load from nib? you can specify the ImageView in your nib and connect it with your ViewController. Then you must alloc-init it every time the cell is created, instead you simply set the attribute cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"superimage.jpg"];

Comment: you are right, but it still doesn't solve the problem. i Still have leaks: GSFontGetFamilyName, GetFontNames, GSFontGetFullName, GetContexctStack, WebThreadCurrentContext. The ones with font are connected with the same line, loadNib

Comment: go through all your leaks and see if you can bypass all alloc-init statements. For example NSString's are dubious for me. If I alloc-init a string use it and then release it I will get EXC_BAD_ACCESS if not copied it. Maybe your other leaks come from anywhere else, edited: set owner:nil

Comment: there are no other leaks connected with code. i can't find anything, that can be connected. it's really strange

Comment: What is more strange, i don't have any leaks in simulator? Is this normal behavior?

Comment: maybe a "Clean All Targets" will help ;)

Comment: can you cut off all the unnecessary parts and send me the project with leaks? then I will figure out whats the problem ;)

Comment: that won't be probably easy, but if i won't find any other answer i will appreciate it. How can I contact you?