# Memory leakage when Running on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-leaks

My Iphone Application running HTTP Live Stream through url and when i am playing it on My Iphone it is showing Memory Leakage.

Here is the Leakage Showing.

```
Leaked Object = GeneralBlock-64 (64 bytes size)

Responsible Library = UIKit

Responsible Frame = GetContextStack
```

ONLY WHEN I AM RUNNING IT ON IPHONE IF SIMULATOR NO LEAKAGE THERE.

PLEASE HELP....

Comment: use the instruments to detect the function which making the leak and show us its code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lot of strange leaks in instruments only on device (no leaks in simulator)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518105/lot-of-strange-leaks-in-instruments-only-on-device-no-leaks-in-simulator)

Comment: Try using the Profiler or post some code to be checked out. The question is not very obvious!

Comment: [[player view]setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 37, 480, 210)];
 player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
 [player.view addSubview:loadView];
 [player prepareToPlay]; 
 [player play];
Also using Instruments with iPhone so getting this leak and Instruments with simulator no leak...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check whether you are running your code in main thread or child thread,if you are working with UI Elements you must run your code on UIThread only.so check ur code once

Comment: yes My application loading contents for server so and it is taking 4-5  seconds that why to present the view from user i create another thread.

Comment: so if you are changing any subviews in background thread it will show leaks.so run on UIthread like [self performselectorOnmainTHread.....

Comment: so if i used the mainThread then it will take time to loading the main View of application.

Comment: call service in background thread update data in main thread k

Comment: its a single process calling service getting XML and depends on the xml data create UI.

Comment: This helped me too.  I was calling setNeedsDisplay from a background thread using performSelectorOnBackgroundThread, was an autocompletion error as I had intended to type performSelectorOnMainThread.  Memory leak of 1MB every 5 seconds vanished.